# Convert a Method Syntax to its corresponding version in Linq Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm pretty new at EF and Linq.

Please help me to convert this Method Syntax query to a Linq one.

Method Syntax to retrieve a single scalar variable from my DataBase using EF.

```
string myCategoryTitle = context.CmsCategories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == rowView.CategoryId).Title;
```

`Title` rappresent a propriety/field in my model.

Any idea how to do it using a Linq Syntax?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean using a query expression... in which case, you can't. There's no query expression syntax for `SingleOrDefault`.

You could use this though:

```
string myCategoryTitle = (from x in context.CmsCategories
                          where x.CategoryId == rowView.CategoryId
                          select x.Title).SingleOrDefault();
```

Note that this isn't *quite* the same as the current code, which will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `SingleOrDefault(...)` returns null...

Comment: Thanks Jon for your prompt reply. I'm still a bit confused, in your sample ....so did you use a "query expression" syntax? if not how would you call this syntax? I'm not able to understand the various way in wich I can query EF. Thanls once again for your help! :-)

Comment: @GibboK: Yes, the "from ... where ... select" is query expression syntax. But you should be aware of how you can use LINQ with just the extension methods too.